# Conky: attempt to compare number with nil

Tags: conky, lua

I'm trying to make my own conky script, and I'm having some trouble with a script I'm using. The script is [this](http://u-scripts.blogspot.com/2010/10/graph-widget.html) one. This is the problematic part:

```
{
    name="diskio_read",
    arg="/dev/nvme0n1",
    max=100,
    width=85,
    height=110,
    y=505,
    x=25,
    nb_values=100,
    bg_colour={{0,0x000000,0}},
    fg_bd_colour = { {0,0x49a835,1}, },
    foreground=false,
    fg_bd_size=0.7,
    bg_bd_size=0.5,
},
```

The error it generates:

```
conky: llua_do_call: function conky_main execution failed: attempt to compare number with nil
```

The thing is that I have enabled `format_human_readable = true`, thus causing `diskio_read` to return a value with unit. Now, I have enabled `format_human_readable` because in I use `${mem}` and `${memmax}`.

My question is if there is any way to convert any number or variable (for example, `${mem}`) from a raw number to a human readable number. That way, I can keep `format_human_readable = false` and avoid having troubles with the lua scripts.

The other way around would be to convert from a human readable number to a raw number, and instead leave `format_human_readable = true` and modify the value that I give to the scripts.

Here are the scripts and configs:

[**conky.conf**](https://pastebin.com/aanHp2wF)

[**loadAll.lua**](https://pastebin.com/XrsedbSs)

[**bar.lua**](https://pastebin.com/7zh5yjLK)

[**graph.lua**](https://pastebin.com/j0xgpsjs)

this is how the script looks as is:

[image]